# how to add or replace some character to sting separated by commas

Tags: python, string, algorithm, data-structures

I have some string and I want add small part to it. How can I achieve this in python?

```
string =ass34_ssa ass56_ssa ass78_ssa,ass93_ssa

for i in string :
i.replace("",",")

#i want the string to look like:

string =ass34_ssa,DER_ass56_ssa,DER_ass78_ssa,DER_ass93_ssa
```

Comment: that's not valid Python syntax, also just `string = string.replace(" ", ",")`

Comment: `"ass34_ssa ass56_ssa ass78_ssa,ass93_ssa".replace(" ",",")`

Comment: how can i add DER part to the string look the last line

Comment: Given `s = 'ass34_ssa ass56_ssa ass78_ssa,ass93_ssa'` do `s = s.replace(' ', ',').replace(',', ',DER_')`

Comment: you mean .replace (',','DER_') last part

Comment: i dont think this will work i have tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
string = "ass34_ssa ass56_ssa ass78_ssa,ass93_ssa"

parts = string.split()
# if , is in the string, then split on that
for i in range(len(parts)):
    if "," in parts[i]:
        p1, p2 = parts[i].split(",")
        # remove the old part
        parts.pop(i)
        # insert the new parts
        parts.extend([p1, p2])

new_string = ""
for part in parts:
    if "34" not in part:
        new_string += "DER_" + part
        if part != parts[-1]:
            new_string += ","
    else:
        new_string += part + ","

print(new_string)
```

First, divide the strings into parts if there is a comma in string then further divide that part and add to parts.

2nd, You can add any logic in the 2nd for loop like this `if "34" not in part`.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: hi what if my string looks like :string = 'ass34_ssa' 'ass56_ssa ass78_'ssa_ass93_ssa'

Comment: i don't want two '